# How to make rails-ckeditor to show already existing files in public folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I was using FCk editor and recently moved to ckeditor using( https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor).

But i didn't find a way to show already existing files in my `/public/images/`. Since browsing of rails-ckeditor shows data on the basis of records entered in ckeditor-assets tables.

How can i use it to show already existing images on clicking browsing?